# Apache camel as proxy and query parameter

Tags: apache-camel

I'm trying to build a very simple HTTP proxy, exactly like described in http://camel.apache.org/how-to-use-camel-as-a-http-proxy-between-a-client-and-server.html.

I use wireshark to see exactly what is going on.

When I do a request on `http://localhost:8080/myapp`, the request that is sent to the real server is `http://realserverhostname:8090/myapp?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false`.

When I do a parameterized request `http://localhost:8080/myapp?toto=tata`, the request that is sent to the real server is `http://realserverhostname:8090/myapp?toto=tata`.

So when there is no request param, the endpoint parameters `bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false` are sent to the real server, and if there is param they are not sent.

Can someone explain the reason of this behaviour ?

How can i force camel to NOT send the endpoint parameters, even if there is no request param?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is a bug in the jetty component in camel.
Replace

```
<to uri="jetty:http://realserverhostname:8090/myapp?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
```

with

```
<to uri="http://realserverhostname:8090/myapp?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
```

or

```
<to uri="http4://realserverhostname:8090/myapp?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
```

will solve the problem.

A bug has been created on the jetty-component https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-10064